# Error when launching the application on wildfly 30.0.1Final

Tags: java, logging, jboss, wildfly

I created a simple Java application using the wildfly web server. The application starts, but the console displays an error:

Dec. 31, 2023 1:37:51 PM org.jboss.logmanager.JBossLoggerFinder getLogger
ERROR: The LogManager accessed before the "java.util.logging.manager" system property was set to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager". Results may be unexpected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL4z1.png)

added arguments VM options
with the hope that the error will be fixed. But she stays:
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
-Djava.class.path=$JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logmanager\main\jboss-logmanager-2.1.19.Final

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjhxU.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: This is more of just a warning. It should have been fixed though. You shouldn't need to add the log manager to the class path or set the property. JBoss Modules should handle that.